# Organic reactions reactions memorising

Tags: organic-chemistry

What is the best possible way to learn organic chemistry reactions rather than memorising blindly?

Comment: undersanding reaction mechanisms will surely help you....but before that you need to have a thorough knowledge(not mandatory but useful) of acid-base theory,chemical kinetics,nature and type of reactants etc.

Answer (score 1):

1. Recognize **functional groups**.
2. Be aware what **nucleophiles** and **electrophiles** are.
3. Apply 2 on 1.

Yes, there's more to it, and you still have to memorize *name reactions*, but the upper will definitely make your life a lot easier.