# most frequently used organic (name) reactions

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

The situation: Beside the relevant inventory in the Merck index, [organic-chemistry.org](https://www.organic-chemistry.org/namedreactions/) lists 243 name reactions (as counted on 08-Feb-2018), the [compilation](https://www.elsevier.com/books/strategic-applications-of-named-reactions-in-organic-synthesis/kurti/978-0-12-429785-2) by Kurti and Czako includes "250 selections" (to quote K.C. Nicolaou's introduction), Li's [*general reference*](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783319039787) on the topic "covers over 320 classical as well as contemporary name reactions" yet he equally compiled name reactions relevant to [heterocyclic compounds](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/book/10.1002/9781118092828) to mention a few possible sources.  There may be a significant overlap of content, though.  The discern of nucleophile and electrophile, as pointed out [here](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/46496/organic-reactions-reactions-memorising), or sometimes anthromorphisms like

```
"What would you do if *you* were an electron"
```

([Grossmann book)](http://www.uky.edu/~rbgros1/textbook.html) to ease drawing mechanisms are ackowledged, too.

The question: But, isn't there a *more condensed* list consisting of maybe 50 to 100 organic name reactions most often used reliably in small molecule organic chemistry?  As one possibility for "reliable" I think of reactions potentially used on larger scale (kg-lab, or journals like [Org. Process Res. Dev.](https://pubs.acs.org/journal/oprdfk)) or the ones suggested by computers in the course of an automated retrosynthetic analysis.

Comment: Even though I admit I like the question, I doubt there is a "Leeloo" for "Leeloominaï Lekatariba Lamina-Tchaï Ekbat De Sebat" of all name reactions. Probably defining a field, or how small the "small molecules" are (I suspect you use a definition used by crystallographers) might be helpful.

Comment: @andselisk Frankly, "Leeloo" is new for me and quite to the contrary, rather than collecting all reactions (as if Diderot and d'Alembert were re-born chemists ...) I speculated e.g. Org. Process Rev. Dev. as primary literature already were surveyed like "a typical issue / volume of reactions published consists of 20% reductive amination, 10% Michael/Knoevenagel/Perkin, 5% esterification, 2% Finkelstein, etc.".  Org. Syn. seems to me less suitable here.  Eventually, "small organic molecule", correct, influenced by crystallography, excludes here typical polymers, proteïn / DNA / RNA.